# Node.js , Socket.io access cookie data from subdomain

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I have a php file which connects to node.js using socket.io.

I need to fetch the cookies and use the data in it for creating the response that I have to send back.
Now the problem is my PHP application is at **localhost/subdomain**, while I am running the server at localhost:8124.

So when I use `socket.handshake.headers.cookie` it returns the cookies stored at **localhost** and not at **localhost/subdomain** as a result of which I only get *phpsessid* and not the cookie data.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED !! Just set cookie path "/" in php !! Then it is available throughout the domain !! Leave socket.io and node.js scripts as they are !!

Answer (score 0):

Setting Domain attribute helped me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

My subdomain is formatted as `subdomain.domain.com`

```
res.cookie('token', token, {domain: 'domain.com', httpOnly: true, secure: true, maxAge: 100000, sameSite: 'None'})
```